# comparing two pair of date using Carbon - Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

a user chose date and I get that date and make 3 more dates as below

```
$start_date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date);
$m1 = $start_date->addMonths(1);
$m3 = $start_date->addMonths(3);
$m6 = $start_date->addMonths(6);
```

then I get the database values which I need to compare the dates with as below

```
$model =  Model::WhereDate('start_date','>',$request->start_date)->get();
```

and I loop through them

```
$duration = 0;    
foreach ($model as  $value) {
      if (Carbon::parse($value->start_date)->between($start_date, $m3) || Carbon::parse($value->end_date)->between($start_date, $m3)) {
                $duration = 1;
      }
      if (Carbon::parse($value->start_date)->between($start_date, $m3) || Carbon::parse($value->end_date)->between($start_date, $m3)) {
                $duration = 3;
      } 
      if (Carbon::parse($value->start_date)->between($start_date, $m6) || Carbon::parse($value->end_date)->between($start_date, $m6)) {
                $duration = 6;
      } 
}
```

is there a better way to do this? I'm not OK with comparing like this  `Carbon::parse($value->start_date)->between($start_date, $m6) || Carbon::parse($value->end_date)->between($start_date, $m6)`

PS - this not to get the duration between dates but to compare them in given date range whether it's in that range.the twist is that comparing date is also a  range dates.

I apologies for my language if there is any unclear part; let me know I'll explain it

Comment: why don't you compare the dates, get the difference in months and choose the best choice between 1,3 and 6?

Comment: @chamara sense, if you can, what do you really want to achieve. set duration as 1, 3, or 6 when the given start date is between the start date and end date in the db?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi  this is for adverting the banner in the website. when a user select a date I don't want there be to be a overlap in the dates that the can put there banner in that position of the website. A user can advertise their banner for 1,3,6 months form the selected date. In here I'm checking whether which option is available but I found that this won't work. Please can you suggest me new logic ?